# Barabasi-Albert Algorithm for Constructing Scale Free Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science

I'm trying to construct a scale-free network using the [Barabasi-Albert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barab%C3%A1si%E2%80%93Albert_model) algorithm in C++. I've seen some other questions on here concerning the algorithm (and I'm using an algorithm similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824097/creating-barab%C3%A1si-albertba-graph-with-spacific-node-and-edgs)), but I wanted to make sure that I wasn't misunderstanding something about the mathematics. The algorithm I am using has the following steps:

1. Create an initial completely connected graph with m0 = 10 nodes.
2. Create a new node -- call this new node n.
3. Select a node i in the original connected graph.
4. Draw a random number r from a uniform distribution on [0,1].
5. Set p = k_i/k_tot, where k_i is the number of edges connected to node i and k_tot is the sum of k_j for all edges in the original connected graph.
6. If r

   Repeat steps 2-6 until the graph has N = 30,000 nodes.

When I use this algorithm, the resulting degree distribution is exponential and not a power law as it should be. When plotted on a linear-log plot, the degree distribution is a striaght line over several orders of magnitude; plotted on a log-log plot, the degree distribution is very clearly a curve.

What am I doing wrong? Is my algorithm correct, or is there something fundamental I've misunderstand? By the way: the exponential distribution resulting from my present code is actually really pretty, so I wonder if I've instead reproduced some other well known process instead of preferential attachment.